# Model not training and negative loss when whitening input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, image-preprocessing

I am doing segmentation and my dataset is kinda small (1840 images) so I would like to use data-augmentation. I am using the generator provided in the keras documentation which yield a tuple with a batch of images and corresponding masks that got augmented the same way.

```py
data_gen_args = dict(featurewise_center=True,
                     featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                     rotation_range=30,
                     width_shift_range=0.2,
                     height_shift_range=0.2,
                     zoom_range=0.2,
                     fill_mode='nearest',
                     horizontal_flip=True)

image_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
mask_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

# Provide the same seed and keyword arguments to the fit and flow methods
seed = 1
image_datagen.fit(X_train, augment=True, seed=seed, rounds=2)
mask_datagen.fit(Y_train, augment=True, seed=seed, rounds=2)

image_generator = image_datagen.flow(X_train,
                                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                    seed=seed)

mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow(Y_train,
                                   batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                   seed=seed)

# combine generators into one which yields image and masks
train_generator = zip(image_generator, mask_generator)
```

I am then training my model with this generator :

```py
model.fit_generator(
    generator=train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=m.ceil(len(X_train)/BATCH_SIZE),
    validation_data=(X_val, Y_val),
    epochs=EPOCHS,
    callbacks=callbacks,
    workers=4,
    use_multiprocessing=True,
    verbose=2)
```

But by using this I get negative loss and the model is not training:

```
Epoch 2/5000
 - 4s - loss: -2.5572e+00 - iou: 0.0138 - acc: 0.0000e+00 - val_loss: 11.8256 - val_iou: 0.0000e+00 - val_acc: 0.1551
```

I also want to add that the model is training if I don't use featurewise_center and featurewise_std_normalization.
But I am using a model with batch normalization that performs way better if the input is normalized so that's why i really would like to use the featurewise parameters.

I hope I explained my problem well and that some of you guys may help me because I really do not understand.

EDIT : 
My model is a U-Net with custom Conv2D and Conv2DTranspose blocks :

```py
def Conv2D_BN(x, filters, kernel_size, strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', kernel_regularizer=None):
    x = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides, padding=padding, kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation)(x)
    return x

def Conv2DTranspose_BN(x, filters, kernel_size, strides=(1,1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', kernel_regularizer=None):
    x = Conv2DTranspose(filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides, padding=padding, kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation(activation)(x)
    return x
```

```py
def build_unet_bn(input_layer = Input((128,128,3)), start_depth=16, activation='relu', initializer='glorot_normal'):
    # 128 -> 64
    conv1 = Conv2D_BN(input_layer, start_depth * 1, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    conv1 = Conv2D_BN(conv1, start_depth * 1, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv1)

    # 64 -> 32
    conv2 = Conv2D_BN(pool1, start_depth * 2, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    conv2 = Conv2D_BN(conv2, start_depth * 2, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv2)

    # 32 -> 16
    conv3 = Conv2D_BN(pool2, start_depth * 4, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    conv3 = Conv2D_BN(conv3, start_depth * 4, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv3)

    # 16 -> 8
    conv4 = Conv2D_BN(pool3, start_depth * 8, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    conv4 = Conv2D_BN(conv4, start_depth * 8, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(conv4)

    # Middle
    convm = Conv2D_BN(pool4, start_depth * 16, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    convm = Conv2D_BN(convm, start_depth * 16, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)

    # 8 -> 16
    deconv4 = Conv2DTranspose_BN(convm, start_depth * 8, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    uconv4 = concatenate([deconv4, conv4])
    uconv4 = Conv2D_BN(uconv4, start_depth * 8, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    uconv4 = Conv2D_BN(uconv4, start_depth * 8, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)

    # 16 -> 32
    deconv3 = Conv2DTranspose_BN(uconv4, start_depth * 4, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    uconv3 = concatenate([deconv3, conv3])
    uconv3 = Conv2D_BN(uconv3, start_depth * 4, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    uconv3 = Conv2D_BN(uconv3, start_depth * 4, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)

    # 32 -> 64
    deconv2 = Conv2DTranspose_BN(uconv3, start_depth * 2, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    uconv2 = concatenate([deconv2, conv2])
    uconv2 = Conv2D_BN(uconv2, start_depth * 2, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    uconv2 = Conv2D_BN(uconv2, start_depth * 2, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)

    # 64 -> 128
    deconv1 = Conv2DTranspose_BN(uconv2, start_depth * 1, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    uconv1 = concatenate([deconv1, conv1])
    uconv1 = Conv2D_BN(uconv1, start_depth * 1, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)
    uconv1 = Conv2D_BN(uconv1, start_depth * 1, (3, 3), activation=activation, kernel_initializer=initializer)

    output_layer = Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding="same", activation="sigmoid")(uconv1)

    return output_layer
```

and I create my model and compile it with :

```py
input_layer=Input((size,size,3))
output_layer = build_unet_bn(input_layer, 16)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=metrics)
```

Comment: Could you share us the model architecture? Which activation function are you using for output layer?

Comment: yep i edited my question with my model,I am using sigmoid for output layer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why your model is not learning you should consider two things.
Firstly, since your last layer's activation is sigmoid, your model always outputs values in range (0, 1). But because of `featurewise_center` and `featurewise_std_normalization` the target values will be in range [-1, 1]. This means the domain of your target variable is different from domain of your network output.

Secondly, binary cross entropy loss is based on assumption of "target variable is in range [0, 1] and network output is in range (0, 1)". The equation of binary cross entropy is

[image: eq]

You are getting negative values because you target variable(y) is in range [-1, 1]. For example if target(y) value is -0.5 and the network outputs 0.01, your loss value will be ~ -2.2875

### Solutions

#### Solution 1

Remove `featurewise_center` and `featurewise_std_normalization` from data augmentation.

#### Solution 2

Change the activation of the last layer and loss function that could better suit your problem. E.g `tanh` function outputs values in range [-1, 1]. With slight change of the binary cross entropy tanh function will work for training your model.

### Conclusion

In my opinion using solution 1 is better because it is very simple and straight forward. But if you really want to use "feature wise center" and "feature wise std normalization" I think you should use solution 2.

Since the tanh function is rescaled version of sigmoid function, slight modification to binary cross entropy for tanh activation would be (found from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12767/174766))

[image: eq2]

and this can be implemented in keras as follows,

```py
def bce_modified(y_true, y_pred):
    return (1.0/2.0) * ((1-y_true) * K.log(1-y_pred) + (1+y_true) * K.log(1+y_pred))


def build_unet_bn(input_layer = Input((128,128,3)), start_depth=16, activation='relu', initializer='glorot_normal'):
    # part of the method without the last layer
    output_layer = Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding="same", activation="tanh")(uconv1)

    return output_layer

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3), loss=bce_modified, metrics=metrics)
```

Comment: Oh now that i see the problem i feel dumb
Thank you very much !
I also thought of something : i use featurewise for the generator for the images but not in the generator of the masks so i can keep the sigmoid in the end because my metric is maid to have [0,1] values as input.